# How to write conditional window.location.href with parameters

Tags: javascript

i'm sorry for my english.
I have following javascript line for redirection of webpage.

```
<script>
 window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/example_0/"  + document.location.search;
</script>
```

I need help to modify a url using window.location.href under the following conditions.

Let me explain better, the original url is built like this:

```
http://www.example.com/result.php?clientId=528873&lang=IT
```

I have to make sure that the ?clientId= parameter is read in the url and based on this parameter redirects the user to the correct url through this correct window.location.href command, for example if the clientID is = a 849679 returns this:

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example1.com/example_1/" + document.location.search;
```

while if the parameter is 818586 it redirects the user to the correct url through this command

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example2.com/example_2/" + document.location.search;
```

etc ...
Could someone help me by writing the correct code in full? I'm a landslide and I can't figure out how to do :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) for this depending on your browser support. https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const clientId = urlParams.get('clientId');

if(clientId === '849679') {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example1.com/example_1/" + document.location.search;
} else if (clientId === '818586') {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example2.com/example_2/" + document.location.search;
}
```

Another solution would be to use regexp or another library for extracting the query parameters.

```js
function getParameterByName(name) {
  var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
  return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

const clientId = getParameterByName('clientId');

if(clientId === '849679') {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example1.com/example_1/" + document.location.search;
} else if (clientId === '818586') {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example2.com/example_2/" + document.location.search;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you are very kind, it worked perfectly.

I just wanted to ask you one last thing, since the main url is

http://www.example.com/result.php?clientId=528873&lang=IT

and I would like to add ?a_aid=xxx before ?clientID=528873 it is possible to transform the ?clientID into &clientID in the reconstruction of the url?

That is, I would like to become:

http://www.example.com/result.php?a_aid=xxx&clientId=528873&lang=IT

Comment: It doesn't matter where in the url you put more query parameters. The logic i posted in the answer will look for a specific matching parameter and doesn't care whether it's ? or &

Comment: So whether I leave? or turn it into & is it the same thing?

Comment: queryparameters always needs to start with ?, and the trailing parameters should start with &. 

So ?a_aid=xxx&clientId=528528 should work fine.